# I have a question about delegating multiple event to server

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I want the onTap event to fire only once to prevent duplicate events from being sent to the server.

Is there a way to manage the flag value by just declaring a bool variable for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
bool active = false;


void _yourFunction() async{
  if(!active){
    active = true; // set to true when process init

   await _yourServerCall();

   active = false; // Set false to try again    
  }else{
    // Also you can integrante dialog or something to notify that exist a process in progress
  }
}
```

and depending how are your working, maybe need use `setState((){});` after change state to active var